# Development Environment

Tags: linux, computing-environment

I needed to migrate from Linux to Windows recently. It means, I currently do not own any local enviroment.

I'm looking for sugestions. I have two possibilities:

1. set up in office server
2. buy a VPS

I’m PHP/RoR/Django web-programmer, I co-work with two other programmers.

Unfortunately, I'm afraid of buying VPS as my administration knowledge is quite limited. I can do anything except security stuff. However, next PC in small office might be an issue to.

What way would you choose? Can you help me choosing this decision?

Comment: Hire a sysadmin.

Comment: Or get hosting. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Linode.com, they've got a great VPS service, and they have excellent documentation on setting up an environment for all the things you're developing for.

Comment: I've decided to go with my own LAN server. Learned a lot and I'm very happy with results!